# Gnuplot : Format yaxis in terms of 10^x

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following data:
N Computed Value of pi

```
 y, x
1, 8.0              
10, 3.6             
100, 3.36               
1000, 3.212                 
10000, 3.152            
100000, 3.14316             
1000000, 3.14266        
10000000, 3.1420448         
100000000, 3.14190876   
1000000000, 3.141573084
```

And I am trying format y axis in terms of `10^x`

I used the following code:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,800 enhanced font 'Helvetica,24'
set output "fig.png"

# Title, axis label, range and ticks
set title "Simulations"
set xlabel "Number of Iterations(n)"
set ylabel "Computed  values"

# Legend location and grid

set key top left
set grid   
set ytics out nomirror
set xtics out nomirror
set format y "10^{%L}"


# Plot the data
plot data.dat" using 2:1 title "" with linesp lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
```

But i am getting the following output:

[image]

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to guess what you really want because there were some inconsistencies. Here is what I believe brings you where you want, changes commented in the source file.

```
# Title, axis label, range and ticks
set title "Simulations"
set xlabel "Number of Iterations(n)"
set ylabel "Computed  values"

# Legend location and grid

set datafile separator comma  # gnuplot looks for spaces
                              # you must tell it about the comma
unset key                     # same as title "" as you have in your plot command
set grid   
set ytics out nomirror
set xtics out nomirror
set logscale x                # I guess that's what you want and how it should be
set format x "10^{%L}"        # yr x axis is labeled iterations, so I guess
                              # that's what you want

# Plot the data
plot [][2:10] "data.dat" using 1:2 with linesp lw 2 pt 7 ps 1.5
    # swapped 2:1 so that the iterations are on the x axis
    # introduced a range for y so that it is better to see
    # 'title ""' removed, see 'unset key'
```

This gives you

[image]

May not be exactly what you want but should move you to the next level I hope.